# How do I use the app store without giving my address (or lying)

Tags: ios-appstore

I am helping a friend. I am trying to install some apps on their ipad. In order to do so we had to review their AppleID account information and got stuck at having to provide a postal address (which are mandatory fields).

The apps that I want to download do not need purchasing, or delivery to a physical address, so adding an address doesn't seem to be strictly necessary. So how do I use an AppleID for downloads without giving this information?

Answer (score 1):

You do not generally use the App Store without giving an address.

Apple requires billing addresses and assigns tax revenue based on where your payments originate. They also respond to legal requests for information based on where you claim to be from when you enter into a contract with them per [Apple Privacy Policies](https://www.apple.com/legal/privacy/).

The terms and licenses are detailed here: https://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/

Apple has changed wording in many places where purchase was used to “transaction” so that people don’t misunderstand that Apple requires account holders to provide accurate account information whether you are signing in, downloading a free app or paying for an app license or service.

> You can acquire Content on our Services for free or for a charge, either of which is referred to as a “Transaction". By each Transaction, you acquire a licence to use the Content only. Each Transaction is an electronic contract between you and Apple and/or you and the entity providing the Content on our Services.

The quote above is the wording from the UK portion of the web site.